# Tensorflow: can I define a weighted mean squared error loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've got a data set with the following shape:

```
x1   x2   x3   w   y
1    2    5    3   4
4    6    6    1   2
5    2    7    3   1
1    6    8    1   8
...
```

I would like to predict `y` from `x1`, `x2` and `x3`, with the following loss function (example in Pyhton):

```
loss = numpy.dot(w, (y-y_pred)**2)
```

Is it possible to train a model with this loss function in Tensorflow (or Keras)?

The model must use only `x1`, `x2` and `x3` to predict `y`, while `w` is unknown during inference.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_squared_error

Comment: [`tf.losses.mean_squared_error`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_squared_error) has a `weights` parameter.

Comment: @Maxim In tensorflow v2.11 documentation, I can't find this weights parameter anymore. Any workaround?

Comment: @jdehesa same question

Comment: @DavidH.J. You'd need to look at [`tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MeanSquaredError) these days. When you use the loss (either directly by calling the loss object or indirectly e.g. through [`tf.keras.Model.fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)) you can give a `sample_weight` that scales the calculated loss for each batch element.